# WooCommerce - Remove footer from product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

Hello Everyone I want to remove footer from woocommerce product page. I am not able to find out the pagename, so I can remove **`wp_footer`** code from there.

How can I achieve this?

please guide me.

Comment: It's not recommended to remove the footer from any page, because it may loads a lot of scripts, styles.
What you can do is to add conditional logic to your footer.php like

`if(!is_product()) { load the footer html }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use native conditionals combined together, **`is_cart()`**, **`is_checkout()`** and **`is_account_page()`**, in the **`footer.php`** file of your active theme or child theme, this way to hide some elements from footer (for WooCommerce shop page and products pages):

```
if ( !is_cart() || !is_checkout() || !is_account_page() ) { 

    // On WooCommerce shop and product pages

   // here goes CUSTOM displayed footer code for WooCommerce shop and product pages

} else { // your normal footer code

    // here goes all displayed footer code

}
```

Depending on what you want to hide from woocommerce pages, you will have to adapt it in your existing code, to feet yours needs. **But does not remove wp_footer** to avoid big problems.

Reference: [Official WooCommerce Conditional Tags](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/#customer-account-pages)

---

After that you can [Override WooCommerce Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) using my account templates to fine tune even more WooCommerce behaviors…

Answer (score 1):

You can remove footer from WooCommerce product page -

```
 if (is_product()) {   
   // here is your footer code which you want to display on woocommerce product page
 }
 else {
    // past your all footer code here for other pages
 }
```

use this code in **footer.php** file .

> If you want to learn more, you can check this - [WooCommerce conditional tags](https://nicolamustone.com/2015/09/11/woocommerce-conditional-tags-an-overview/)